# QT SQL bindValue issue

Tags: sqlite, bindvalue

I got problem for using the bindValue in QT with SQLite3.
The below statement don't work.The exec is success but result incorrect.

```
 query5.prepare("select DISTINCT :col_readback FROM Equipment");
 query5.bindValue(":col_readback", "Category");
```

However, if I run the below one statement without any issue.

`query5.prepare("select DISTINCT Category FROM Equipment");`

I have tried to change to another name of the bindValue but it don't work as well.

Comment: You are trying to bind column_name(identifier).

Comment: column name cannot be bind?

Comment: Not really. And with your query you got `SELECT DISTINCT 'Category' FROM Equipment` (string literal) vs `SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM Equipment` (identifier)

Answer (score 1):

Look like bindValue have some problem to work with column field.
I use arg instead and it work
query5.prepare(QString("select DISTINCT %1 FROM Equipment").arg(col_readback));

Comment: String substitution != query parameter binding. Be aware of possible SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Edited out the original answer so the first comment makes no sense now.

Given that you are trying to substitute a column name vs. a value, I would suggest that you simply build the query string and then execute it, skipping the prepare.

```
const QString col = myValFromProgram; // a QString
query5.exec("select DISTINCT " + col + " FROM Equipment");
```

Comment: I have tried this one not work..